# Why does this jquery not slide toggle my php generated list?

Tags: php, jquery

Why does this jquery not slide toggle my php generated list?

I've tried changing a couple of things to get this to work and none worked.

EX: `$('ol>li:has(ol)').click` `$(this).children('ol').slideToggle();` `$(this).siblings('ol').slideToggle();`

PHP:

```
function listFolderFiles($dir){
    $ffs = scandir($dir);
    echo '<ol class="list_hold">';
    foreach($ffs as $ff){
        if($ff != '.' && $ff != '..'){
            echo '<li class="list">'.$ff;
            if(is_dir($dir.'/'.$ff)) listFolderFiles($dir.'/'.$ff);
            echo '</li>';
        }
    }
    echo '</ol>';
}
```

Jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('ol ol').slideUp();
    $('ol>li').click(function(){
        $(this).next('ol').slideToggle();
    });
});
```

HTML example:

```
<ol>
<li class="list">find_folders
<ol class="list_hold" style="display: none; ">
    <li class="list">Thumbs.db</li>
    <li class="list">find.css</li>
    <li class="list">find.php</li>
    <li class="list">index.php</li>
    <li class="list">minus.png</li>
    <li class="list">plus.png</li>
    <li class="list">test folder
        <ol class="list_hold" style="display: none; ">
            <li class="list">bananas</li>
        </ol>
    </li>
</ol>
</li>
</ol>
```

Comment: Please provide a copy of your post PHP html. The php snippet you provided doesn't give us a clear view of what jQuery actually has to work with.

Comment: .next() shouldn't work because your nested `<ol>` lists are children of the `<li>` elements and .next() works on siblings. You should use find() or children().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your supplied html, you'll need to do something like this:

```
$('li:has(ol)').each(function () {
    $(this).children('ol').slideUp();
    $(this).on("click", function (event) {
        event.stopPropagation();
        $(this).children('ol').slideToggle();
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/farneman/n2Arc/2

The main issue is that your selectors were not correct with your actual html.

Comment: I've updated my code and provided a working fiddle. Take a look and see if that accomplishes what you're looking for. If it's still not working at all then there's probably some other issues with your code that we can't diagnose based on the supplied info.

Comment: This seems to work, do you know what I would have to add to have sublists slid up too? once I open a main folder all the folders under are open (because they weren't slid up I think)

Comment: Sorry about that, just changing the `.find` to `.children` fixes that issue: http://jsfiddle.net/farneman/n2Arc/1/

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('ol ol').slideUp();
    $('ol>li').on("click", function(){
        $(this).next('ol').slideToggle();
    });
});
```

---

`on` works for dynamically generated content, such as what is created by PHP's `echo`. The `echoed` elements aren't present on the page when you add the click handler to them; that's why your click event isn't working.

Can't see from your PHP what your HTML looks like but you might need something like this?

```
$('ol>li').live("click", function(){
    $(this).parent().next('ol').slideToggle();
});
```

Assuming that your HTML looks something like this:

```
<ol>
    <li> </li>
</ol>

<ol>
    <li> </li>
</ol>
```

The issue is that `this` refers to the element clicked (the `<li>` in this case), which in your case doesn't have an `<ol>` siblings. You need the sibling of the parent of the `<li>`, the next `<ol>`.

Answer (score 0):

Might want to try this:

```
$('ol ol').slideUp();
$('ol>li').click(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    $(this).children('ol').slideToggle();
});​
```

You're using .next() which works on sibling elements but your ordered lists are actually children of the parent lists. In that case you'd want to use a selector like find() or children().

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/JQCdm/)**.